# Как во Vue 3 получить данные из другого, глубоко вложенного, компонента

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Структура следующая, есть модальное окно (компонент modal), внутри него другой компонент (назовем оболочкой внутри модального окна, компонент settings), внутри этой оболочки находится панель tabs-panel, а уже внутри нее находится компонент формы с нужными мне данными (компонент ep-form).
Так вот, внутри оболочки (компонент settings) есть кнопка, по нажатию которой я хочу получать данные из формы (ep-form).
Модель структуры:

```
--modal
----settings (панель оболочка, в которой есть кнопка по нажатию которой получать данные из формы)
------tabs-panel
--------ep-form (из селекта внутри этого компонента нужно получить данные)
```

Упрощенный код:

```
/* Модальное окно */
<template lang="pug">
div
  div(class="flex-1")
    slot(name="body")
  div
    slot(name="bottom-toolbar")
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'modal',
  props: {
    modalShow: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
})
</script>

/* Оболочка внутри модального окна */
<template lang="pug">
div
  modal(v-model:modalShow="modalShow")
    template(v-slot:body)
      tabs-panel
    template(v-slot:bottom-toolbar)
      def-button(@click="toast(); checkAndCloseModal();") OK

<script>
name: 'settings'
methods: {
  checkAndCloseModal() {
    /*
     Получить данные из компонента ep-form,
     а конкретнее value из select(name="type-list") (см.ниже)
    */
  }
}
</scripts>

/* tabs-panel внутри оболчки панели */
<template lang="pug">
div
  ep-form
</template>
<script>
name: 'tabs-panel'
</script>

/* ep-form внутри tabs-panel */
<template lang="pug">
div
  select(name="type-list")
    option(
      v-for="item in getItems"
      :value="item.id"
      :key="item.id"
    ) {{ item.name }}
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ep-form'
}
</script>
```

Подскажите как просто можно получить value из селекта? По цепочке прокидывать пропсы как-то не очень, через CompositionAPI я так и не понял как можно (и можно ли вообще)

Comment: Vuex / ref (Composition API) / Event bus.

Comment: А форма что делает? Просто данные отображает? Или как-то, куда-то их передает?

Comment: @Дмытрык форма содержит данные ранее подтянутые из БД (хранится во Vuex и getter`ом ставится), пользователь может что-то изменить и надо сохранять.

Comment: В принципе я нашел решение, с помощью библиотеки `mitt` (что-то наподобие event bus как предлагал @yar85), но в 3-й версии сами разрабы считают такой подход антипаттерном, но в тоже время в крайних случаях ссылаются на эту же библиотеку.

Comment: В экосистеме вью сейчас по-моему _вообще все_ кроме композишки стало считаться антипаттерном, но как-то пофиг... мода меняется, это нормально.

Comment: Имхо, кроме вьюэкса все равно ничего лучше не придумают - с разделением аппстейта на модули (ui, api, ...) да с геттер-фабриками (для серийного создания дженерик геттеров), он решает почти все проблемы связанные с обменом инфой между компонентами... и во многом благодаря подпискам на мутации (тот же event bus, вид сбоку) и постоянному пребыванию в памяти. Это по сути комбайн, который в плане глобальной циркуляции данных могёт практически все. А мапинг геттеров и действий с мутациями в компонент - это та же композиция, хоть и со вкусом синглтона вместо импортов.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу приходят два варианта

1. Простой способ. Через `this.$children` Подробнее [тут](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/children.html#overview)
2. Использовать [store](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/), но потребуется интеграция на все приложение, что может быть излишним

**UPD**. Сорри, в последних версиях vue вырезали первый вариант, попробуйте через [refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html#template-refs)

Comment: я пробовал использовать refs, но как я понял он вызывается только как `this.$refs...`, в моем случает контекст между компонентами, естественно, меняется и обратиться так не получится, или я что-то не так понял?